# Dev express Grid View column header size

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

Is there a property of a grid view control that can set the text size of a column header?

Answer (score 0):

For that controll you have a  `HeaderStyle` Porperty

For example:

```
<HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
```

Well explained at MSDN:

[Formatting the GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to mention that it needs to be server side. figured it out.

Me.Grid.Columns(columName).HeaderStyle.Font.Size = 50